# Regex and python: substituting $$ with \[ and \] in a TeX document

Tags: python, regex, replace, tex, file-conversion

**EDIT:
regex with testing, examples and solution here: https://www.regex101.com/r/rY7uI4/2**

I am trying to convert a TeX content (which we will assume to be contained in the variable `foo`) so that the delimiters `$$` will be converted to the standard TeX `\[` and `\]`. I have been playing around with regex101 but until now no luck.

Ideally, the expected result is that given this input:

```
text
$$ math $$

$$
math
$$

text $$math$$ text
```

the output is the following

```
text
\[ math \]

\[
math
\]

text \[math\] text
```

Maybe regexp are not the best tool to do that, but I found no other tool to accomplish the task. Thanks for any help!

EDIT:
to add a more complex (and realistic) testcase:

```
$$\alpha \quad \beta \quad \varepsilon \quad \varphi \quad \mathbb{R} \quad \mathcal{C}([0,1]) \quad \mathfrak{R}([0,2\pi]) \quad \mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R})$$
$$\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad \underline{x}\in \mathbb{R}^m, \quad \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^m \$$$string
```

should result in:

```
\[\alpha \quad \beta \quad \varepsilon \quad \varphi \quad \mathbb{R} \quad \mathcal{C}([0,1]) \quad \mathfrak{R}([0,2\pi]) \quad \mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R})\]
\[\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, \quad \underline{x}\in \mathbb{R}^m, \quad \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^m \$\]string
```

Note the prescence of an escaped $ at the end of the second string.

Comment: Can't you use the simple `str.replace`?

Comment: If you want to replace fixed strings (not *patterns*) with other fixed strings, the standard issue string replace function is what you want. Don't overcomplicate things.

Comment: Unfortunately str.replace will replace all the occurences it finds, while I only want, for every couple of `$$`, the first `$$` to be replaced with `\[`, and the second with `\]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a non-greedy regex.

```
print re.sub(r'\$\$(.*?)\$\$',r'\[\1\]',s)
```

If you don't want to consider the escaped dollar symbol then use a negative lookbehind for checking whether the last `$$` is not preceded by a backslash character or not.

```
print re.sub(r'(?s)(?<!\\)\$\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$\$',r'\[\1\]',s)
```

Add DOTALL modifier `(?s)` at the start to make dot in your regex to match also the newline characters (*line breaks*).

Comment: almost perfect, even if it will fail this: `$$test\$$$ string`

Comment: so you don't want to consider escaped $ ? try `\$\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$\$` or `(?<!\\)\$\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$\$`

Comment: yes, exactly. It's almost there, however, this breaks if the input contains newlines (that appear quite frequently, too).

Comment: then add a DOTALL modifier at the start like `print re.sub(r'(?s)(?<!\\)\$\$(.*?)(?<!\\)\$\$',r'\[\1\]',s)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.sub` with [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) as following :

```
>>> import re
>>> s="""text
... $$ math $$
... 
... $$
... math
... $$
... 
... text $$math$$ text"""
>>> print re.sub(r'\$\$\s?(\w+)\s?\$\$',r'\[\1\]',s)
text
\[math\]

\[math\]

text \[math\] text
```

`\1` is the first group matched in your regex pattern in this case `(\w+)`

Edit: for if you may have more text between `$$` as you add in your edit you just need to change `\w` that match word characters with `.+` to match any character with length more that 1.

```
>>>re.sub(r'\${2,}\s?(.+?)\s?\${2,}',r'[\1]',s)
```

Comment: hi! thank you, the first version indeed is correct (I need `\[`, not `[`), and I confirm it works!!!

Comment: I am sorry, I spoke too early: a string such as `$$\alpha \quad \beta \quad \varepsilon \quad \varphi \quad \mathbb{R} \quad \mathcal{C}([0,1]) \quad \mathfrak{R}([0,2\pi]) \quad \$ \mathscr{C}(\mathbb{R})$$` (very typical in a TeX document) is not recognized by that regexp.

Comment: @Roophie so whats your expected output for that? can you add it on your question?

Comment: @Roophie `>>> print re.sub(r'\${2,}\s?(.+?)\s?\${2,}',r'[\1]',s)`